# How to specify priority in makefile

Tags: gcc, makefile

I have a makefile and several targets there. I want to clean directory first, then build directories and then run compilation of tasks1..4. Sometimes building directories starts after compilation and this makes compilation impossible.

Makefile in general looks like:

```
release: clean
release: build
release: task1 task2
release: task3 task4
```

Clean and build must be finished before tasks1..4 start running. In other words how to specify priority in makefile tasks. Now seems all 4 lines from the makefile start altogether in one moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using `-j`; without parallel builds enabled `make` will never start any rules together: it always runs them one at a time in the order the prerequisites are listed.

The only way to specify order is via prerequisites.  So, this would look like:

```
release: task1 task2 task3 task4
task1 task2 task3 task4: build
build: clean
```

However, this last step is a very bad idea: you don't want your build target to depend on clean in general, otherwise it will always be run.  You can either ask people to run clean by hand, but probably the most common way to deal with release targets like this is with make recursion:

```
release:
        $(MAKE) clean
        $(MAKE) build
        $(MAKE) task1 task2 task3 task4
```